# QGIS: Converting a QVariantlist from a GeoJSON to a List with some prefix removed

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

I have some problem seeming to converting a QVariantList from a GeoJSON file to a list in a new shapefile.
Every time I just do the expression "Column" and just put the type of data as List in the Refactor Fields algorithm.
The data vanishes, in other words it becomes completly empty (not even the NULL is Showing).

There is one exception for one pecular column. You see there is a column with a kind of prefix so to remove that prefix from some thing like "Type1:Type1a:Actual value" to "Actual Value" I did this formula.

```
 CASE WHEN "references"  IS NOT NULL THEN
string_to_array("references" ,':')[2]
ELSE
NULL
END
```

***Problem is it only will keep the first record in the list***
I want to have all the values here because the reference column is a link column. There are three columns being in Qvariantlist, **only the column references contains a prefix I want to have removed all the rest does not need a prefix removal.**

[image]

Edit: 5/07/2020:
The Sollution provided by Thomas is putting me in the right direction the formula .

array_to_string("Field",',') does make sure I truly get the data back as a string but even  though I select the data to be a list in my refactor fields I still cannot set as a list in my arribute forms.

[image]

Allso to note that the formula that the formula Thomas had provided cause my field to go empty. If I do array_to_string alone it is fine but as soon as I do his, formula to remove the prefix of something like this:

```
Pipe:AWeVe:P7224741f-fa8f-4503-8b04-4f654ca294f1,Pipe:AWeVe:P8e69091d-cc9c-436a-8357-a3e85eb8495 
Or TelecommunicationsCable:InfraDEFRegio5:43565,TelecommunicationsCable:InfraDEFRegio5:4357
```

To:

```
P7224741f-fa8f-4503-8b04-4f654ca294f1,P8e69091d-cc9c-436a-8357-a3e85eb8495 
    Or 
43565,4357
```

What needs to removed in EACH value is the substring that goes to the second ':' mark.

EDIT 2: **Let me be clear here that in the references column in the screenshot that sometimes in that you Columns there is only one value in the list.**

Answer (score 1):

Normally the following expression should do what you want. We loop to get a first list (coma separated) then within this list we loop and keep only the suffix and we finish by concatenating again the result.

Tried with multiple elements

```
array_to_string(
  array_foreach(
    string_to_array('Pipe:AWeVe:P7224741f-fa8f-4503-8b04-4f654ca294f1,Pipe:AWeVe:P8e69091d-cc9c-436a-8357-a3e85eb8495', ','),
    string_to_array(@element, ':')[2]
  ),
  ','
)
```

Tried with one element

```
array_to_string(
  array_foreach(
    string_to_array('WaterPipe:FARYS_TMVW:WP-019', ','),
    string_to_array(@element, ':')[2]
  ),
  ','
)
```

Comment: Okay your formula is going in the right direction One Big problem though I still lose the data in the fields that are not seperated by a comma. In otherwords the fields that have only one value in the array.

Comment: Not sure I understand. I've edited my answer using the same code with one value in the array. If misunderstanding, can you edit your question to provide exact sample string or add a comment with the sample, please?

Comment: For example this: array_to_string(
 array_foreach(
 string_to_array( "references", ','),
 string_to_array(@element, '')
 ) , 
 ','
 )
"references" is the column where that data is.

Comment: Instead of "references" that suppose I have the same database as you, give me the exact problematic string you see. Otherwise not possible to debug locally on my computer to help you.

Comment: For Example: 

Pipe:AWeVe:P7224741f-fa8f-4503-8b04-4f654ca294f1,Pipe:AWeVe:P8e69091d-cc9c-436a-8357-a3e85eb8495
Or

TelecommunicationsCable:InfraDEFRegio5:43565,TelecommunicationsCable:InfraDEFRegio5:43571

Comment: These examples already works with my code. You mentioned "In otherwords the fields that have only one value in the array." What do not work in this case? Can you provide a string sample for this?

Comment: For example this one:WaterPipe:FARYS_TMVW:WP-019. This an example of only one value in the array in the same column.

Comment: It clearly seems I'm missing something in your explanations: your sample works too with without coma and only one value.

Comment: Your code makes the fields empty that only have one vallue. WITH the Prefix removal (string_to_array(@element, ':')[2])  I only get the first value in the list: For example the  Pipe:AWeVe:P7224741f-fa8f-4503-8b04-4f654ca294f1,Pipe:AWeVe:P8e69091d-cc9c-436a-8357-a3e85eb8495. Translate only into:
P7224741f-fa8f-4503-8b04-4f654ca294f1, While in reality it should be this:
P7224741f-fa8f-4503-8b04-4f654ca294f1, P8e69091d-cc9c-436a-8357-a3e85eb8495.